# php shorthand to append to object

Tags: php, laravel, object, shorthand

I'm pulling through data from my database and wish to add an object to the end of each item. The following code works, but I'm assuming there's a better way than repeating all the info and adding to a new object.

```
    $cs = $client->contact()->get();

    foreach ($cs as $c) {

        $contact = (object)[
        'id' => $c->id,
        'name' => $c->name,
        'role' => $c->role,
        'phone' => $c->phone,
        'address' => $c->address,
        'postcode' => $c->postcode,
        'otherClients' => Contact::find($c->id)->clients()->get(), //this is the additional info
        ];

        $contacts[]=$contact;
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? Seems like you might be able to add a repository method to get the contacts with their client list already attached.

Comment: Creating an array that you cast into an object while you actually have the object doesn't really make sense IMHO. If you only want to add an object to your object, you can simply do it by creating a fake property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply mutate the original objects if you don't need to leave `$cs` intact.

```
foreach ($cs as $c) {
    $c->otherClients = Contact::find($c->id)->clients()->get();
}
```

Comment: if we won't pass address does it push `key => value` in main parent array?

Comment: @AjayKumar if you're referring to the `&$c` in your answer then that is only necessary in PHP4. Here, OP is using PHP5.4+

Answer (score 1):

you can use

As suggested by @MrCode

```
$cs = $client->contact()->get();
```

**PHP 5.4+**

```
foreach ($cs as $c) {

    $c->otherClients = Contact::find($c->id)->clients()->get(), //this is the additional info
}
```

**PHP 4 Or below**

```
foreach ($cs as &$c) {

    $c->otherClients = Contact::find($c->id)->clients()->get(), //this is the additional info
}
```